# How to pop alert message on google spreadsheet when "reopen" open the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to pop alert message when every time someone opens the sheet.

```
function alertMessage() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("alert message");

}


function alertMessageYesNoCancelButton() {
  
  let a=3;

  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Alert message", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO_CANCEL);

  while(a<5){
 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(result);
  }

}
```

When I click run button and choose the function name to run it, the alert message will only show once.

[image: the result]

When I reopen the sheet, the alert message is gone. When I send the link to someone who I share the sheet, they can not see the alert message too.

Comment: Please do not use images for code and/or errors and output, always paste it as text and format properly. Try to provide information in English, your error (or warning, I cannot even say) is in language barely anyone here can understand. It is hard to help when you can't read what is wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

I found I need to change my function name to `onOpen`. This function is triggered every time, someone opens the spreadsheet .

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp, or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene)